# Priority Queue Not Sorting

Tags: c++, stl

Im trying to implement my own Huffman Coding algorithm and the priority queue for the C++ STL does not seem to be working correctly. I am taking characters from a string and inserting them into a priority queue by order of their frequency in the string. The code compiles and runs without error, the only thing is the tree seems to not be sorting correctly. Here is the code,

```
class Node {
 public:
  int freq;
  char data;
  Node(int &f, char &d) { freq=f; data=d; }
  bool operator<(const Node* &n) const { return n->freq < this->freq; }
};

void Init(priority_queue<Node*> &tree, string input) {
 map<char,int> probability;
 for(int i=0 ; i<input.size() ; i++) {
   probability[input[i]]++;
 }
 map<char,int>::iterator it = probability.begin();
 for(it ; it != probability.end() ; it++) {
   Node* blah = new Node(it->second, (char&) it->first);
   tree.push(blah);
 }
```

}

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: dupe of / same as [How to implement sorting method for a c++ priority\_queue with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986021/how-to-implement-sorting-method-for-a-c-priority-queue-with-pointers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are storing pointers in the `priority_queue`, so the elements are sorted by pointer value, not using your `operator<` overload.

You either need to store `Node` objects in the priority queue, or you need to write a custom comparison function for the priority queue that dereferences the stored pointers and compares the `Node` objects they point to.

Since you ask "what am I doing wrong?," here are some other suggestions:

- Your `operator<` overload should take a const reference, not a reference to a pointer.
- Your `Node` constructor should take its parameters by value, or at the very least by const reference.  The cast `(char&)it->first` is not good.  Let `const` help you write good code, don't fight against it.
- You probably should store `Node` objects directly in the priority queue, not pointers.
- You are using `using namespace std` somewhere; you should remove this and spell out `std::` wherever you need to.

Comment: Ok, so I understand the operator taking a const reference, and not one to a pointer, and having the PQ take Nodes instead of pointers to Nodes worked. What about the rest though? Why should the constructor take parameters by value, why shouldnt I use "using namespace std", and why is type casting to get rid of const bad practice?

Comment: @Zach: You don't change the parameters, so why pass the parameters as though you will?  If you had done so, you wouldn't need that dangerous cast later.  Why is that cast dangerous?  Because map keys aren't supposed to change; if you change one, the map might not be sorted anymore and you've now broken the entire container.  `using namespace std;` defeats the entire purpose of putting things in a namespace to begin with.  You've introduced all sorts of opportunities for subtle bugs due to overload resolutions, name clashes, and the like.