# priority_queue of objects that point to each other

Tags: c++, pointers, std, priority-queue

I have a class `Node` that, in addition to storing data, has a pointer to its parent `Node`. I store some Nodes in a `priority_queue` and overrode the `<` operator for comparison.

```
class Node {
public:
    string name;
    Node *parent;
    int cost;
};

static bool operator<(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) {
    return lhs.cost < rhs.cost;
}
```

```
priority_queue<Node> queue;
```

The problem is, the parent pointers seem to be messed up. My guess is, that when I pop a `Node` from the queue, the `Nodes` are actually moved up in memory and the pointers point to wrong `Nodes`. Could this be?

I tried to use a `priority_queue` of `Node*` pointers instead (and create them with `new`), so that only the pointers are reordered, not the objects themselves. This seems to fix the pointer issue, however now the queue is ordered by memory adress, and not the cost of the `Nodes`.

How can I implement a `priority_queue` that has objects pointing to each other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement sorting method for a c++ priority\_queue with pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986021/how-to-implement-sorting-method-for-a-c-priority-queue-with-pointers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Node*` and a custom comparator for your queue. With what you currently have, you can do the following, though i suggest you use smart pointers if they're available in your current toolchain.

```
class Node {
public:
    string name;
    Node *parent;
    int cost;
};

class CompareNodePtr
{
public:
    bool operator ()(const Node*& left, const Node*& right) const
    {
        return left->cost < right->cost;
    }
};

// your priority queue with custom comparator.
std::priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*>, CompareNodePtr> myqueue;
```

Alternatively, for a more local-defintiion of the comparator, you can stuff the compare-my-pointer class within `Node` so as not to pollute the global namespace:

```
class Node {
public:
    string name;
    Node *parent;
    int cost;

    struct ComparePtr
    {
        bool operator ()(const Node*& left, const Node*& right) const
        {
            return left->cost < right->cost;
        }
    };
};

// your priority queue with custom comparator.
std::priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*>, Node::ComparePtr> myqueue;
```

Regarding pointers being "messed up", with object-level storage (as opposed to pointer-storage as above) your priority queue can/will move elements around each time it re-heapifies the content after a pop (in case you weren't aware, the standard lib uses a heap structure for a priority queue by default).

Finally, I leave the notion of how to deal with a parent-pointer of some node being popped prior to any/some of its children, being deleted, and thereby creating an invalid pointer to any children left in the queue to you, but it sounds like you're aware that can happen.

Comment: I get this compile error: `No matching function for call to object of type 'CompareNodePtr'`. Since it is in the same header file as `Node`, I think it should be included correctly. Do I need to include anything for the comparator class to work?

Comment: @Jawap I'd put it either right under your Node definition, or even more local, *in* the Node definition as a subclass and referenced by scope (`Node::ComparePtr`) for example. but yes, it needs to be declared prior to the declaration of the priority queue. If you would like me to update the answer to demonstrate the local subclass ideology let me know.

Comment: @Jawap also, i forgot the `public:`, in there. its been updated. that was, perhaps, the problem in the first place (I usually use structs when doing this).

Comment: Alright, I got it working. Thanks a lot for your hel! And for the hint about memory management. I'm aware of those issues, I'm just new to C++.